# How to insert <sup> tag into simple_form label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, label, simple-form

How to insert `<sup>2</sup>` into simple_form label so that the end result for the label would be: **Meters (m<sup>2</sup>)**

```
<%= f.input :meters, label: "Meters", placeholder: "Meters" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple .html_safe should do it.

```
<%= f.input :meters, label: "Meters (m<sup>2</sup>)".html_safe, placeholder: "Meters (m<sup>2</sup>)".html_safe %>
```